# WordPress custom setting page - add flashing message

Tags: query, settings-api, screen-options

I have a custom settings page for my plugin that has in the same page a submit button and a link like `http://mysite.dev/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-page&action=update-cache&_wpnonce=mynonce`

By now I can check the `wpnonce` successfully as well as show the message. The problem is: when I click the link to perform it's action and then submit my form, the link action will still be there.

The things by now are like this:

I have an action in `admin_init` which validates the nonce and if it's valid redirect to `http://mysite.dev/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-page&cache-clean=1`. The part `cache-clean=1` from query indicates that my action was performed.

I realized that normally WordPress does that when you update a post adding `settings-updated=true` do query string, and then redirects to the edit page. After this, the message shows up once.

After looking out on the code, I've realized a filter named `removable_query_args`, which seems to automatically remove (redirect) when the URL has a value set in the array of this filter. Even adding my query arg there, didn't work with the message because I don't know now to sinalize that there were a redirection.